# Regex positive lookahead multiple occurrence

Tags: regex, regex-look-ahead

I have below sample string

```
abc,com;def,med;ghi,com;jkl,med
```

I have to grep the string which is coming before keyword ",com" (all occurrences)

Final result which is I am looking for is something like -
`abc,ghi`

I have tried below positive lookahead regex -

```
[\s\S]*?(?=com)
```

But this is only fetching `abc,` not the `ghi`.

What modification do I need to make in above regex?

Comment: `\w+(?=,com)` matches [both](https://regex101.com/r/t2FXXQ/1).

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: `[\s\S]` Matches any character which in this context is too much. You can also opt for a capture group `([^\s,;]+),com\b` See https://regex101.com/r/yUXluH/1

Comment: Hi Fourth Bird, Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It worked :).

Answer (score 3):

Using a character class `[\s\S]` can match any character and will also match the `,` and `;`

What you can do is match non whitespace characters except for `,` and `;` using a negated character class and that way you don't have to make it non greedy as well.

Then assert the `,com` to the right (followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match)

Instead of using a lookahead, you might also use a capture group:

```
([^\s,;]+),com\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yUXluH/1) with the capture group values.